# Flutter - How to navigate to another page on an asynchronous value

Tags: flutter, triggers, setstate

I'm trying to show a splash screen on initial app startup until I have all of the data properly retrieved.  As soon as it's there, I want to navigate to the main screen of the app.

Unfortunately, I can't find a good way to trigger a method that runs that kind of Navigation.

This is the code that I'm using to test this idea. Specifically, I want to run the command `Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home');` when the variable `shouldProceed` becomes true.  Right now, the only way I can think to do it is to display a button that I need to press to trigger the navigation code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:catalogo/src/navigationPage.dart';

class RouteSplash extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RouteSplashState createState() => _RouteSplashState();
}

class _RouteSplashState extends State<RouteSplash> {
  ValueNotifier<bool> buttonTrigger;
  bool shouldProceed = false;

  _fetchPrefs() async { //this simulates the asynchronous function
    await Future.delayed(Duration(
        seconds:
            1)); // dummy code showing the wait period while getting the preferences
    setState(() {
      shouldProceed = true; //got the prefs; ready to navigate to next page.
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchPrefs(); // getting prefs etc.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: shouldProceed
            ? RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  print("entered Main");
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'home'); // <----- I want this to be triggered by shouldProceed directly
                },
                child: Text("Continue"),
              )
            : CircularProgressIndicator(), //show splash screen here instead of progress indicator
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So, in short, how can I trigger a function that runs the Navigation code when shouldProceed changes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is after you get the preferences, just navigate to the screen and have the build method just build a progress indicator.

Try this:

```
_fetchPrefs() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("home"); //stateful widgets give you context
}
```

Here's your new build method:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

I've made a DartPad to illustrate: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/431fcd9a1ea5748a82506f13be042e85

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  I think that my simulation of the _fetchPrefs wasn't accurate enough.  The data would actually come from something like: shouldProceed = Provider.of<ProductData>(context, listen: true)
        .shouldProceed;    That's why I'm looking to track the method trigger on the change of the external value.

Comment: I'll mark this as answered (since it was in the confines of the original question) and create a new question using a Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Create a widget which can be shown or hidden similar to my ProgressBar code.   Show and hide based on a timer or when the data load from the api has completed.

```
    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    progressBar.show(context);

     Provider.of<Api>(context, listen: false)
      .loadData(context, param)
      .then((data) {
      progressBar.hide();
      Provider.of<Api>(context, listen: false).dataCache.login = loginValue;
      Navigator.pop(context, true);
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/home");
    }
  });
```

replace the ProgressBar code with your splash screen:

```
 class ProgressBar {

    OverlayEntry _progressOverlayEntry;

    void show(BuildContext context){
        _progressOverlayEntry = _createdProgressEntry(context);
        Overlay.of(context).insert(_progressOverlayEntry);
    }

    void hide(){
        if(_progressOverlayEntry != null){
        _progressOverlayEntry.remove();
        _progressOverlayEntry = null;
        }
    }

    OverlayEntry _createdProgressEntry(BuildContext context) =>
        OverlayEntry(
            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                        top: screenHeight(context) / 2,
                        left: screenWidth(context) / 2,
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    )

                    ],

                )
        );

    double screenHeight(BuildContext context) =>
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    double screenWidth(BuildContext context) =>
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

  }
```